# How do you replace the default navdrawer icon in android?

Tags: android

I want to change the default DrawerLayout icon on the upper left side to my own image but I don't know why it does not work on load of app. The icon only changes when I have opened or closed the side menu. I also want to disable the animation, it is disabled after I changed the icon but that only happens after it is opened and closed. I don't know why this does not work on load of the activity

```
actionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.custom_screen_toolbar);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
    drawerLayout, actionBar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            actionBar.setTitle("Nav Menu Close");
            actionBar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.action_bar_menu);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            actionBar.setTitle("Nav Menu Open");
            actionBar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.action_bar_back_icon);
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    actionBar.setSubtitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(
            R.color.light_gray));
    actionBar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.divider_action_bar);
    actionBar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.action_bar_menu);

    setSupportActionBar(actionBar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe calling `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` will cause the navigation icon to be set to the back arrow icon, in addition to providing the default behavior of finishing the activity when it's selected.

You should be able to remove that line and `setHomeButtonEnabled(true)` to get the effect you want.